# Which transformation technique should we use for 2 bell shape distribution?

Tags: machine-learning, data-visualization, data-transformation, exploratory-data-analysis

I'm doing exploratory data analysis and trying to transform the feature with log transformation, but I'm not sure which transformation to use for the two bell shaped distributions. Is it required to apply transformation for these kind of distributions?

[image: sns.distplot(pco_energydata['log_forecast_meter_rent_12m'])]

Comment: Why would you want to transform this at all?   It appears that there are three distinct peaks, at least, and those peaks are probably correlated with something else.  There's  information there!

Comment: Whatever transformations you use, you will still have three peaks ... transformations will be of no help.  Better ask your real questiond, and try to understand what those peaks are!

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen - not to be *too* nitpicky, but rank-based transformations will eliminate the peaks, e.g., the ranks themselves or a Normal scores transform.